# Is the Go programming language replacing C++?

Tags: c++, go

I have read on some blogs that Go is a better system programming language and is going to replace C/C++. I am currently learning C++. So, I was wondering whether I should continue learning C++ or move to Go?

Comment: Why not learn both (eventually)? I recommend `C++` to anyone who ask me the typical; I want to code, but I dont know what language to learn.

Comment: Do you have friends, classmates, or acquaintances with the sort of career you'd like to get? Ask them what they use. A mature programmer knows plenty of languages, though. They're just skills to be picked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go is designed for reliable, fast online services. It's the recommended language of Google App Engine. It does have general feature parity with C, plus additional scalability features. Perhaps, one day, it will be adopted for embedded programming and client-side applications, but that has yet to happen.

C is used in many, many application domains. No other language approaches its breadth of use. As a first language, though, it won't help you develop good habits.

C++ is a multi-paradigm language. It supports deep, generic metaprogramming. Many users of C++ are really using "embedded domain-specific languages" (EDSLs) where a library provides functionality defined within the C++ grammar. Go does not attempt to provide this depth, which is a Pandora's box of complexity.

Comment: Go has no parity with C, as C is garbage collected.
I have been programming in C++ for about 10 years and I have never used a "embedded domain-specific language". It is certainly not the normal way of using C++. "Deep, generic metaprogramming" is not the norm. You can use if you want. But many users of the language do not (Google itself does not use templates).

Comment: I think you mean *Go* has garbage collection, which would be an additional feature. You are only one person, not many. Generic programming is useful for writing libraries, including the standard library, which Google (and most everyone else) does use. As for programs, yes it's pretty optional.